# List all registered routes in Vertx

Tags: java, vert.x, vertices

Is there any way (like in a symfony application) to list down all the available/register routes on a vertx server? I am facing an issue that my registered route is returning a 404 on running restassure tests.

Comment: Are you using vertx-web ? If so, use ```Router#getRoutes```(http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/Router.html#getRoutes--). You should check whether you use the good verb, path, and headers for vertx to route the request to the good endpoint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but you have to write a bit of code to achieve that.

```
// Example router setup
Router router = Router.router(vertx);
router.route(HttpMethod.GET, "/").handler(routingContext -> {
    routingContext.response().end("Root");
});

router.route(HttpMethod.GET, "/users").handler(routingContext -> {
    routingContext.response().end("Post");
});

router.route(HttpMethod.POST, "/users").handler(routingContext -> {
    routingContext.response().end("Post");
});

// Getting the routes
for (Route r : router.getRoutes()) {
    // Path is public, but methods are not. We change that
    Field f = r.getClass().getDeclaredField("methods");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Set<HttpMethod> methods = (Set<HttpMethod>) f.get(r);
    System.out.println(methods.toString() + r.getPath());
}
```

This will result in:

```
[GET]/
[GET]/users
[POST]/users
```

Comment: `Route.toString()` lists this information and more without reflection. That might have been added to `toString()` after this answer was posted.